# Вывод типа double без "плавающей" запятой

Tags: java

Моя программа выводит результат в таком виде

> 12.0

Нужно чтобы выводило просто

> 12

Знаю, что можно перевести в строку и сделать форматированный вывод, но есть ли более простые варианты?
P.S. код на Java

Answer (score 4):

Привести к целому типу. Дробная часть будет просто отброшена.

```
    double val = 10/3;
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println((long) val);
```

Сравните результаты вывода.

Как правильно заметил коллега в ответе ниже, приведение к целому типу может привести к ряду проблем в случае, когда значение больше чем Long.MAX_VALUE или эквивалентно NaN/Infinity.

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", val)
```

Данный код правильно отформатирует значение в любом случае (для null не выведет ничего).

Comment: А можно поконкретнее, как привести к целому типу? Есть какой то стандартный метод?

Comment: Добавил пример кода. Но лучше все-таки использовать String.format() и иже с ним.

Comment: У вас `val` -- `double`, так что `null` быть не может.

Comment: @VladD это никак не меняет того факта, что в случае null ничего выведено не будет :)

Comment: Ну это да :-) В общем, опасаться нечего.

Answer (score 3):

Это прекрасно сделает System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", val)).
В том числе и для NaN и Infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Эта задача легко решается стандартными средствами:

```
double[] values = new double[] { 12.0, 13.33, 15000.0144 };

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);

for (double d : values)
{
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format(d));
}
```

Результат:

```
12
13
15 000 // при включенной группировке позиций
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, преобразование в `long` проблематично для достаточно больших значений переменной, а так же для INF и NaN.

Я бы предложил конверсию через `BigDecimal` и `BigInteger`:

```
if (Double.IsNaN(val) || Double.IsInfinite(val))
{
    System.out.println(val);
}
else
{
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(val).toBigInteger().toString());
}
```

---

Мой код неэффективен, воспользуйтесь советом [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura). Оставляю его лишь для полноты.

ЗЫ: Заметьте, что подходы дают немного разный ответ: [через String.format](http://ideone.com/PI7xyk), [через BigDecimal](http://ideone.com/RHZKdZ).

Answer (score 0):

Объявите просто переменную-результат, как int и больше можете об этом не заботиться в дальнейшем, результат всегда будет только как целое